# Laravel form validation

Tags: forms, laravel, validation

What I want to do is to pass current user's id to create a new link that belongs to that user. When I hit submit it keeps showing error  message: user id field is required. I think there might be a mistake in my controller action, but can't figure it out.

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkOTf.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Link::create(array_merge(request(['title', 'address', 'category_title']), ['user_id'=>$user]));
```